# How do I remove shapes formed by other touching shapes in adobe illustrator

Tags: adobe-illustrator

I have 4 circular shapes as shown in the screenshot. I want to remove the area marked A and B that forms around where the 2 small circle touch and the inner and outer circle. How do I do this?

[image]

This is another look of it. To the left is what i have to the right is the final shape i want to obtain.

[image]

Comment: Use shape builder. Although there may be a better way to model this particular shape.

Comment: I haven't been able to do it with shape builder. See my latest question update.

Comment: Adjust your gap detection. Anyway you should probably just delete a sector of a circle put a stroke on it and expand. Since then tou wouldnt need to do the rotations that are needed for accurate registration of the shapes. Rembember a bezier circle is only approximate.

Answer (score 2):

- Select All
- Grab the **Shape Builder Tool**
- Depress and hold the <kbd>Option/Alt</kbd> Key
- Click `A`, then click `B`

More information regarding Shape Builder can be found by reviewing the [Help Files](https://helpx.adobe.com/illustrator/user-guide.html/illustrator/using/creating-shapes-shape-builder-tool.ug.html).

[image]

---

Or, simply draw a thick stroke with *rounded* end caps and then remove part of the circle.

[image]

Use `Object > Expand` afterwards if you want a shape rather than a stroked path.

Comment: I couldn't make it happen following this steps. I edited the original question and added another image showing what i have and what the final intended shape is. I appreciate your help.

Comment: @user2503480 The steps work... not sure why they don't for you. See updated answer with animations.

Comment: @suer2503480 - this does definitely work, I just tested it. Double click your Shape Builder tool and enable Gap Detection.

Comment: Yes the gap detection trick did it! Thanks